# What are the catalysts in eightfold path which speed up our endeavor?

Tags: eightfold-path, samadhi

I want to know how one can speed up his spiritual practices (8 fold path). For- Example, How one can improve his samādhi or prajñā quickly? And what are the things or acts which helps one to improve these quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best catalyst is meeting highly realized people in real life to see how they behave. In a day of that you get more teaching than in a year of reading books.

Comment: Difficult to find. What to do meanwhile?

Comment: [Seclusion](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.6.02.than_en.html)

Comment: I used to live in a monastery with supposedly highly realised people, which had 1000s of students  & visitors per year. I recall maybe one or two or three but not many more of those visitors attained samadhi. Ajahn Brahm said somewhere in a video he teaches jhana to so many but so few attain it. Only last year, at least 3 of his monks & nuns disrobed.

Answer (score 0):

The way to speed up samadhi is to practise according to the instructions, which are to use 'letting go' ('the giving up of craving', called 'vossagga') as the meditation object.

> And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a
>   monk, a disciple of the noble ones, making it his object to let go (vossagga),
>   attains concentration, attains singleness of mind.
>
> SN 48.10

---

> And how are the seven factors for awakening developed & pursued so as
>   to bring clear knowing & release to their culmination? There is the
>   case where a monk develops mindfulness as a factor for awakening
>   dependent on seclusion, dependent on dispassion, dependent on
>   cessation, maturing in relinquishment (vossagga). He develops analysis of
>   qualities as a factor for awakening... persistence as a factor for
>   awakening... rapture as a factor for awakening... serenity as a factor
>   for awakening... concentration as a factor for awakening... equanimity
>   as a factor for awakening dependent on seclusion, dependent on
>   dispassion, dependent on cessation, maturing in relinquishment (vossagga).
>
> MN 118

Answer (score -1):

Since right view is the foundation, [all deeds, actions and undertakings, increasing right view](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/wijesinghe/punna_en.html#top) are of use to establish the.

Focus on the foundations! It does not make sense to try to gain right Samadhi if the virtue section is not good developed. Practice generosity and service for those worthy. Practice sharing merits... Practice Veneration...

If having trouble with performing those meritorious deeds, no way to think that it is possible to gain right concentration.

> For a person facing Stress and suffering and meeting the Tripple Gems, there is no act of will, 'May I gain conviction'. It is the nature of things that in a person, facing Stress and suffering and facing the Tripple Gems, conviction is gained.
>
> For a person with conviction, there is no act of will, 'May I be generous, may I have possibility to give, my I let go of stingyness'. It is in the nature of things that, in a person of conviction, generosity and giving is established.
>
> For a person of generosity and freedom of stinginess, there is no act of will, 'May I become virtuous'. It is the nature of things that, in a person of generosity and freedom of stinginess, virtue increases.
>
> further: [Cetana Sutta: An Act of Will](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,1998.msg13724.html#msg13724)

If there is [still stinginess, not even Jhana can be reached](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.254.than_en.html).

Once there is no more fault in regard of virtue, no stingyness present, it will work naturally on the given causes.

And like always: to develop right view, association with people of right view is most importand. More on [entering the stream here](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html).

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial use or other lower wordily gains by ways of exchange or trade]*

Comment: How do monks, who have nothing, abandon stinginess? Thanks

Comment: By answering merely ill-willed and back-stabbing approches, for example, @Dhammadhatu ? Stinginess is not just a matter of material things. Good to investigate this topic well, for example lack of gratitude is also a very sign of Maccariya. E.g. not - vossagga

Comment: Sorry. But vossagga is the path to jhana rather than generosity. If generosity was the path to jhana, all of the peasants in Cambodia who give to monks would abide in jhana. I scored your post down because I think it is deceiving; including the quote, which i have not read in any sutta.

Comment: That's what was said. Do as you are fit. Blind in a low realm one is not able to understand Dhamma. * rowf * [stingy...](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.254.than_en.html), an "animals-states" attitude. vossagga = giving, letting go, generosity. And if not even outwardly able... than dream on the other realms dreams.

Comment: Enough with you two troublemakers. You are both suspended for 1 week. Please use the time to contemplate how you want to behave on Buddhism SE.